# How can I merge multiple cells without losing text data and without using a formula?

Tags: excel, merge, excel-2010, data-cleaning

When importing data from an email I receive daily, I have to go through and clean up a column which has sets of rows like the one I've demonstrated below. What I would like to know is how to merge column B's data into row 1 so I can then delete the now empty rows 2 and 3. I've seen formulas for concatenation and the like, but that requires keeping the data. As soon as I clean this data it is moved to another sheet.

Thank you for your help.

```
|--------A---------|---------B--------|--------C---------|
1  Important Data  |  Important Data  |  Important Data  |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
2    Empty Cell    |    Empty Cell    |    Empty Cell    |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
3    Empty Cell    |  Important Data  |    Empty Cell    |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: what is the pattern in the data? is there only going to be 3 rows every time? or do you want to concatenate 3 rows into one for each 3 rows?

Comment: Did you find anything here useful?

Answer (score 0):

You may write a Sub for concatenating, and replacing B1 with the result.

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    s = ws.Range("B1").Text & ws.Range("B2").Text & ws.Range("B3").Text
    ws.Range("B1") = s
    ws.Range("B2:B3").Clear
End Sub
```

This is the essence. Then if you need to repeat the operation, etc., it can be adapted.